# How to rsync only a specific list of files to the same location on another server

Tags: awk, rsync, scp

I have a list of files:
/location/file.txt

Content of file:

```
/location1/file2.abc
/location2/location3/file1.abc
/location4/location5/fileX.cde
```

I'd like to copy files to another sever like this:

```
cat /location/file.txt | xargs -i scp {} user@server:/location
```

but in the above example all of files from the list are copying to specific location, while I'd like to copy them to the same locations (accurate path as in the txt file /location1/, /location2/location3/ etc.

How can I do it? I can also use rsync, but I'd like to enter password (to remote server) only once.

Comment: FYI: to avoid multiple-password-entry, if you are using SSH keys, you can use `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add` to enter the key's password only once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
rsync -av --files-from=/location/file.txt / user@server:/location/
```

That will copy the local file `/location1/file2.abc` to `/location//location1/file2.abc` etc.

As `rsync` will invoke `ssh` only once, you only have to enter the password once. You may want to investigate using ssh keys though.

Comment: Ok, but if I want to copy all of files from the list to exactly same location on remote server I should use following command? 

rsync -av --files-from=/location/file.txt / user@server:/

Comment: @Qmski almost. You will need to add the `-R` flag, too: `rsync -avR ...`

Comment: In case your list of files includes a directory _tree_ which you want to copy, and _in addition_ to the `-av` and `-R` ("relative"), you will also need the seemingly-redundant-but-not `r` flag. From the man page regarding `-a` : "The only exception to the above equivalence is  when --files-from is specified, in which case -r is not implied."

Comment: @roaima note that `--files-from` implies `-R` so you don't have to add that!

Comment: @Otheus you usually will want to preserve permissions, owner, group, time etc. so I usually just use `-a`; but at least `-ptgo` should be used.

Comment: Yep. I had a brain-fart. @wurtel

Comment: @wutel so it does. Sorry.

Comment: What if I want all the files to go in a single directory, regardless of where they came from?

Comment: @Michael then you need to modify the file list given to `--files-from` to replace the last `/` with `/./` which is a magic marker for the `--relative` (`-R`) option, which represents the root for the relative transfer.